# C# Calling events from within the constructor

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, constructor

Is it possible to call/trigger/throw/fire (don't know what the correct term is) events from inside a constructor in C#?

The reason I am asking is that I have a dilemma: I have a form that takes very long to initiate(go through its constructor) because it needs to load lots of files. So, I want a splash/loading screen to appear until the main form is initiated. Moreover, I want to update the splash screen with updates telling it what has loaded so far and what has not.

I run the splash screen in a separate thread and want to send the messages about what has loaded through events. Unfortunately, it seems I cannot fire events from within the constructor of the main form. Anyone have any suggestions as to what I could do? Or how I would trigger events from within a constructor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working in winform, WPF?

Comment: Constructor should be for initializing the state of a class. Then everything else appears. And in your case it looks like you load it with inappropriate logic. So put the logic and events into separate method, say `Init`.

Comment: What type of application are you working on? WPF, Windows Phone, etc..
Have you tried loading the files asynchronously?

Comment: @jmaster18 and X-TECH:  I am working in winform

Comment: @Artyom The problem with an **Init** method is that if I run it from within the constructor, it becomes a part of the constructor, so there is no difference in the way the program acts, except the code is written differently. On the other hand, if I call it after I have started the application (outside the constructor) than it doesn't get executed until after the program window is closed because the constructor is that of a windows form.

Comment: @user2636234 Why call it from within constructor when the whole point not to? The second point is not clear. There are a lot of events in `Control` or `Form` classes if WinForms is concerned. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Other (WPF) is similar. Usual thing.

Comment: @Artyom Thanks, Im dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `winform` then take a look on the following code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form //Your initial form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LaunchWorkForm();
    }
    private void LaunchWorkForm()
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.OnStatusUpdated += form2_OnStatusUpdated;
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void form2_OnStatusUpdated(string status)
    {
        //message comes from Working Form
        //Invoke UI thread and update UI here
    }
}
```

Now, this is your form or dialog having a lot of work to do

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void UpdateStatusHandler(string status);
    public event UpdateStatusHandler OnStatusUpdated;
    public Form2()
    {
        //Start thread here
        if (OnStatusUpdated != null)
        {
            OnStatusUpdated("I am going to start work");
        }
        //Doing a lot of work here
        if (OnStatusUpdated != null)
        {
            OnStatusUpdated("Some of work has been done");
        }
        //Do other
        if (OnStatusUpdated != null)
        {
            OnStatusUpdated("Now I am ready to load the form");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question may help you

[C# constructor event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243923/c-sharp-constructor-event)

It contains event calling procedure from constructor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass in arguments to the constructor, then you can use a callback. Something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Action<Progress> callback)
    {
        // Do work here...  
        callback(progress);
        // More work, etc.
    }
}
```